# MakerCluster onmousehover change icon with google map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

i am using [google-map-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react) and [markerclusterer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/markerclusterer) and on cluster marker hover need to add differet svg icon. but somehow mouseover is not working

```
const renderer = {
  render: ({ count, position }) =>
    new maps.Marker({
      label: {
        text: String(count),
        color: '#ffffff',
        fontSize: '14px',
        fontWeight: '600',
      },
      icon: {
        url: 'assets/svgmarker.svg',
        scaledSize: new maps.Size(45, 45),
      },
      position,
    }),
};
const markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer({
  map,
  markers,
  renderer,
  algorithm: new SuperClusterAlgorithm({
    radius: 200,
    gridSize: 20,
  }),
  onClusterClick: onClusterClickHanlder,
});

maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'mouseover', () => {
  console.log("click");
});
```